# How to add a hotspot in android google panorama API

Tags: android

I am trying to make a android panorama app using Google panorama API.
I am able to load the panorama image and view it in my application.
But I am not able to add a hot spot/marker on the image.
Can anyone help me resolve this issue???

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: I am looking for the same feature of a hotspot. Did you found any solution for the same ?